# Cannot connect to database mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, database, database-connection

I cant connect to database, working on new pc.
Here are params with which i access my sql database :
[image: sql]

My connection string in Web.config is :

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=DMITRIJSS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=HRM_MVC_DEV_Test;user id=BTG\DmitrijsS;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="HRMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HRMModel.csdl|res://*/HRMModel.ssdl|res://*/HRMModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DMITRIJSS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=HRM_MVC_DEV_Test;user id=BTG\DmitrijsS;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When I am trying to access db it throws window where I have to write password, when I leave it blank -
Login failed for user BTG\DmitrijsS

Comment: are you accessing sql sever from same machine ?

Comment: yes, i`m trying to access from the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=DMITRIJSS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=HRM_MVC_DEV_Test;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="HRMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/HRMModel.csdl|res://*/HRMModel.ssdl|res://*/HRMModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DMITRIJSS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=HRM_MVC_DEV_Test;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: thank you it resolved my problem, but could you explain what was my problem, and why it was working on prev. pc

Comment: i think there is problem with database authentication

Answer (score 0):

Set up environment variables. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms365307.aspx